# Why my code in R do not compile with Date() function?

Tags: r

### MYCODE

```
setwd("~/R/Scripts - todos/Dolar")
dolardia <- read.xlsx ("com3500.xlsx", sheet = "Hoja1")
view(dolardia$FECHA)
str(dolardia$FECHA)

col1 <- as.Date(dolardia$FECHA, format= "%d/%m/%y")
```

### THE PROBLEM

```
col1 <- as.Date(dolardia$FECHA, format= "%d/%m/%y")
```

> Error in as.Date.numeric(dolardia$FECHA, format = "%d/%m/%y"):
> 'origin' must be supplied

Comment: Try 
col1 <- as.Date(dolardia$FECHA, format= "%d/%m/%y", origin = "1970-01-01").

Comment: it´s don´t have an error, but the information is not correct. because when i try to see it with a view(col1), show me NA for all obs

Comment: Maybe `col1 <- as.Date(as.character(dolardia$FECHA), format= "%d/%m/%y")` will work? It's hard to say without out a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). What does `class(dolardia$FECHA)` return?

Comment: Hola Dieguexz. Could you please paste the output that the following code will generate? 
dput(head(dolardia))

Comment: No me deja pegar o adjuntar imagenes...

Comment: Pero puedes editar el texto y pegar el resultado de dput().

Comment: It would be very useful to put an example of the dates that you're trying to parse. There have been several answers and you haven't put a MWE yet.

Answer (score 0):

If the date is recent (i.e. after Unix epoch - January 1st, 1970), you could try

```
col1 <- as.Date(dolardia$FECHA, format= "%d/%m/%y", origin = "1970-01-01")
```